# Why does the separate() function in R output like this? How do I avoid this?

Tags: r, tibble

I am trying to separate the second column ('text') of this tibble into multiple columns based on the "," separator in using separate(). However, the output I am getting has "wins = 4" etc. instead of just "4" in each cell. How do I get around this so the cells are not modified in this way?

This is the initial tibble I am trying to change:

Initial tibble

[image]

This is my code:

```
'''
new_all_team_tbl <- all_team_tbl %>%
separate(text, c("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5", "col6", "col7", 
"col8"), ",")

new_all_team_tbl
'''
```

This is the output I am getting:

New tibble

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: `text` column is a list so use `unnest_wider` instead of `separate`.

Comment: what would be the syntax in my case for using unnest_wider Ronak?